# MySql : SELECT * from table > and get affected_rows OR SELECT COUNT(*)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just curious about one thing and i don't know if there is any real big difference on the back-end code execution , which one eats more resources (like RAM / CPU) to return the required data .

We have this example :

```
SELECT * from table
```

From the above query we can get the `affected_rows` > which has the count of the rows &&  table data.

The question comes here:

Should i use

```
SELECT * from table > and use `affected_rows` for the count
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

is there any big difference ?

Comment: if you want only count then go for `COUNT(*)`, but if you want data (to do something on it further) then use `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: i know that , but my question here is if there's any real big difference that should make me use count instead select * and get affected_rows instead ??

Comment: Never use `SELECT *` under any circumstances.

Comment: `SELECT *` does just that. It selects every column and every row in the table. `SELECT COUNT(*)` only gives back a single number. It should be quite obvious what you should use if all you need is the amount of rows in a table.

Comment: it's simple, `SELECT *` gives you data as well. So it will consume more RAM/CPU usage. What's big deal to understand that?

Comment: OK , i asked this because i didn't know if SELECT COUNT does ONLY COUNT and not doing same SELECT * and return only affected_rows as a result , you get my point here ? why do i asked ? , i don't know how does it work on the backend code .

Comment: something useful: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/06/15/sql-server-solution-puzzle-select-vs-select-count/

Comment: @mitkosoft this answers my question well enough , thanks for the link ! 

From the website post : 

count(*) is about counting rows, not a particular column. It doesn’t even look to see what columns are available, it’ll just count the rows, which in the case of a missing FROM clause, is 1.

Comment: @AlinRazvan You ask "is there any big difference". The answer is: Yes. Imagine a table with millions of records. Getting all this with `SELECT *` causes A LOT of overhead when all you are interested in is the number of rows. If that isn't what your question was about, then you need to clarify your question, I'm afraid.

Comment: @waka i asked this because i didn't know how the mysql function on the backend when it comes to SELECT COUNT(*) ,you get my point here ? look #mitkosoft shared a link which explains it well enough for me

Comment: @AlinRazvan: "you get my point here ?", no I'm afraid I don't. You asked about `SELECT * FROM table` whereas the linked article talks about `SELECT *` without a table. It should be of no surprise that `SELECT * FROM table` also holds the value of the affected rows, because it selects everything from said table. Then you ask "is there a huge difference" and the answer is still: Yes.

Comment: @waka it answers my question because it does also explain how does COUNT(*) works on backend , and how does SELECT * works on backend , which is what my question is about , why should i use one and not the other what are the differences, please read the first lines of my question , thanks for your answers as well , you were on point , but i was interested on what are the differences on the backend execution of each function , should i select * from table and get affected_rows (count) or should i just select COUNT(*) to get my count .

Answer (score 2):

Without digging into much technical details, consider data transmission. "SELECT * FROM table" will be transferring lots of data compared to "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table". This will increase the data transferring time. Which is usually larger than the execution time for simple queries like this.

Below screenshot shows execution times against my local mysql instance (Macbook pro 13-2015, Corei5). As you can see with SELECT * it's the fetch time that becomes the bottleneck. But if I select only one record (3rd entry), it returns the result faster than SELECT COUNT(*).

[image: Query execution time]

So actually there's no guaranteed answer. But consider below,

- Using two mysql commands vs one command
- Lag/ data transmit duration between your client and server
- Size of your database

I assume you are referring to a large dataset. In that case SELECT COUNT(*) would be the better option considering all the facts.

Comment: Thanks @dryize for this comparison , it improves the knowledge regarding my question , i wasn't sure about some things already answered on this post , that is why i asked in the first place , some people here answer without even reading the question well , i was interested on how does mysql do things on the backend when it comes to count(*) or select * > affected_rows , so therefore which one eats more resources , your answer is ok ,@mitkosoft shared a link which explains how count works on the backend https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/06/15/sql-server-solution-puzzle-select-vs-select-count/

Comment: From the website : 

The engine performs a “Constant scan” for Count(*) where as in the case of “SELECT *” the engine is trying to perform either Index/Cluster/Table scans.

When you query ‘select * from sometable’, SQL replaces * with the current schema of that table. With out a source for the schema, SQL throws an error.

so when you query ‘select count(*)’, you are counting the one row. * is just a constant to SQL here.

Answer (score 0):

For the above question, `'SELECT * from table'` which will give  all the data which contains in your table But `'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table'` it will give the number of rows contains in your table...

Comment: SELECT * from table gives you all the data but at the same time it does return affected_rows which holds the count as well !

Answer (score 0):

Usually, to get the count from Table, the correct procedure is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

It's a corrective and fast method to get the count from a table.

But If you use `SELECT * from table` It will select all the data from the table and If you have N number of data in the table it will time to retrieve the data.